# How to create client_assertion and assertion in on_behalf_of flow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get access token with a certificate.

I know values of these client_id, grant_type, scope from my application.

But where can I find values of assertion and client_assertion.

Do I need to get more tokens, I'm completely lost here.

Can anyone guide me with working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample. It can be summarized as:

1. go to this url to get auth code:

> ```
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
> client_id=aad_client_id
> &response_type=code
> &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
> &response_mode=query
> &scope=api://aad_client_id_which_exposed_api/permission_name
> &state=12345
> ```

2.use auth code to generate access token by auth code flow.
3. use access token to generate another access token by obo flow.

[image]

On behalf flow is used when an API want to call another API. So at first you need to have a web api which is protected by AAD, so that it can receive an access token A. After having this token A, on behalf flow can generate a new token B by A, so A is the value for parameter `assertion`. Then using `client id + client secret` and follow [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) to generate access token by obo flow. And this is what I do in the screenshot.

Azure AD also also us to use `certificate` rather than `client secret` to complete the authorization. So we can also follow [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate) to do it. As you can see, missing `client_secret` but appear `client_assertion_type client_assertion`.

Then the only issue left is how to get the token A. Just like what I say, token A is used for visiting API which is protected by AAD, so you need to expose an API and give the api permission, then update your project to authorize the scope right? Then [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview) demonstrate the whole progress. Finished all the steps, then you may need to sign in with your `onmicrosoft.com` account first, then you can get a `code` from the url in the browser, then use that code to generate an access token, this token should had scope like `api://aad_client_id/xxx`， and this is token A.

[image]

You may also refer to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-overview), this can help you understand obo flow.

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve CORS problems during dev testing? I'm trying to implement this same auth flow but when I call Microsoft API to get the code I'm getting a CORS error.

Comment: `call Microsoft API to get the code I'm getting a CORS error` we need to use the ms library to trigger the sign in and getting code action, but not simply send an http request in your code to trigger the action. I had a test before in a SPA which sending ajax get request to start sign in flow but got CORS issue. After I used MSAL.js, it worked.