# Microsoft Graph - OAuth2.0 flow for React client and spring-boot backend

Tags: reactjs, spring, azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I am building a React-based SPA that communicates with a spring-boot backend via a REST API. I need the user to be able to log into their Microsoft account on the browser client (the SPA) and I need the backend service (spring-boot app) to be able to query Microsoft's Graph API on behalf of that user.

After reading up on the Oauth2 flows, the authorization code flow (not the PKCE flow, just the regular authorization code flow) seems the most appropriate. The browser client could let the user log into their Microsoft account, retrieve an authorization code, and send the authorization code to our backend service via HTTP request. The backend service (which is trusted and can safely store a client secret) can then request an access token, make requests to the Graph API directly (meaning that the SPA would never need to make any requests to the Graph API), and silently refresh the token as needed.

However, I cannot see any examples of anyone using this flow to access Microsoft's Graph API.

Looking at Microsoft's documentation, it seems like they recommend using the [on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow). But this flow requires the browser client to request an access token and then use that to communicate with the backend service (which in turn can communicate with the Graph API). It doesn't make sense to me why the access token cannot be requested on the backend using a client secret. Wouldn't this be a more secure and preferred method than having the client retrieve the access token, as is done in the on-behalf-of flow?

The [Oauth2.0 site](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/which-oauth-2-0-flow-should-i-use), recommends that SPAs should either use the authorization code with PKE or the implicit flow, but I do not see an option to use the standard authentication code flow for SPAs. Should I take this as an indication that SPAs should not be using the standard authorization code flow as I described earlier?

Despite not finding a clear-cut example of the standard authorization code flow in Microsoft's documentation for a react frontend + java backend, I tried to go about doing this myself. However, using the `@microsoft/mgt-react` and `@microsoft/mgt-element` libraries to do this are not straight forward. For example, the `@microsoft/mgt-element` notion of a `Provider` supports a call to retrieve an access token, but doesn't clearly expose the authorization code. If I wanted to do the authorization code flow described earlier, it seems like I would need to use raw HTTP requests, which I know is not a recommended way of accomplishing this.

**Summarizing my questions:**

- **What OAuth2.0 flow should I be using: 1) authorization code (access token is retrieved by backend service using client secret), 2)
  authorization code with PKE (access token is retrieved by client), or
  3) on-behalf-of flow (access token is retrieved by client, seems to be an extension of PKE flow)?**
- **If using the on-behalf-of flow, does the SPA just include the access token in the header (marked as 'bearer') and the backend service just
  includes that same header to query the Graph API, or does the backend
  service need to request another token before querying the Graph API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @ch4mp to call graph api directly in SPA if it's allowed. If not, then I recommend you using `on-behalf-flow` or `client credential flow` based on your requirement.

Let's come back to your requirement -- call ms graph api in a springboot api project. First, let's see one of the graph api [getting user api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). You can see permission types here: Delegated which means call graph api on behalf of the user, Application which means calling api on behalf of the application(your spingboot api project) itself. If you want to call api behalf of the user, then you have to use on-behalf-of flow. This is because the api project which will be considered as a daemon application, so the project itself doesn't have a UI page to let users enter username/password to sign in and get authenticated.

You can certainly use ROPC flow which have to pass the username/password to api but I really think it unsafe, so I don't recommend.

If it's not necessary for you to call graph api on behalf of user, you can certainly take client credential flow into consideration. But pls note here, application type api permission is a "large" api permission which always have name like `User.ReadWrite.All, Mail.ReadWrite.All` and it always means the application can not only query user information but also be able to modify user information.

If you want to use on-behalf-flow, then you may review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74311506/how-to-create-client-assertion-and-assertion-in-on-behalf-of-flow/74313765#74313765) and it explained the whole progress...

Comment: Thanks @Tiny_Wang! One clarification -- why can't I request the auth code from the SPA, pass it to the backend service using an HTTP request, and then have the backend service request the access token itself using the client secret / auth code? I don't see anyone using this pattern in the examples, but these feels the most intuitive to me. Will this not work?

Comment: in my humble opinion, passing a jwt token to the api project then let the api project send http request to call graph api should be able to get graph api response. but it may bring more traffic for your server.(I'm not sure if this is the reason why we never see anyone using this pattern in the examples ) when a user connect to your api project, then your api project will have a new instance to prepare http request elements and send to call graph api.

Answer (score 0):

I would use authorization-code flow (with PKCE) to get an access-token and then refresh-token flow to "maintain" this token, both from client.

Authorizing the request to your resource-server with this token only makes sense if Microsoft authorization-server is your main authorization-server. Otherwise (user also logged in with an authorization-server of your own or not using OAuth2 betwean React and backend), you can still send Microsoft access-token in request body.

In any case, when issuing requests in the name of the user from the backend, do as you suggest: just set the access-token sent by the client as Bearer Authorization header (token is retrieved either from Spring security context or request body). Backend fetches a new access-token (using client-credentials flow) when issuing requests in its own name (without the context of a user).

Side note: have you considered calling Microsoft API directly from React client? If you don't have to store the result of that call on your resource-server (i.e. call graph API to display data and store only what user selected from that data), that would save quite some latency on the client and costs (network and CPU) on the backend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @ch4mp. We do in fact need to make the calls from the backend since we want to be able to continue making calls on behalf of the user even after the user has closed the browser application (the idea is that we could silently refresh the token in the background). I have one question — in the on-behalf-of-flow, can you just request an access token from the backend service using the access token provided from the client? Is it the same url as I would use to request an access token normally (providing access token instead of authorization code)?

Comment: This `on-behalf-of` flow is nothing standard. It is completely Microsoft stuff which means that most libs won't support it and you''l get troubles some day when trying to move to another authorization-server.

Comment: You could have client post the refresh token to a dedicated endpoint, but be careful, what you are doing really isn't recommended. Does your backend really need to issue those offline requests on behalf of a user (can't it use client-credentials flow)?

Comment: Unfortunately, we do need the backend to issue offline requests on behalf of a user. We were thinking that, using the on-behalf-of flow: 1) the client could get an access token using auth-code flow (with PKCE), 2) client could send a HTTP request to the backend with the access token included as Bearer Auth header, 3) backend could request its own access token somehow (not clear on how this is done) from Graph API, and 4) backend can refresh its access token to prevent it from expiring. Does this model work, or would we need user input to refresh the token?