# Client Secret not included in Access Token

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We use MSAL and Azure AD for authentication.

We have a client and several microservices (that are not hosted in Azure)

The calls from the client to the microservices work fine. But we need also to make calls between the microservices. We are trying to do this using a token that uses a client secret, with the following code:

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .WithAuthority(authority)
        .Build();

    var aquireTokenForClientParameterBuilder = app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes);

    var token = await aquireTokenForClientParameterBuilder.ExecuteAsync();
```

When we try to call the service it fails with:

```
    WwwAuthenticate {Bearer error="invalid_token"}
```

When I look in the token with jwt.io, I cannot see that the client secret is in the token.

Any ideas how to fix this, or an alternative way to call between services?

Comment: The Microservice making the call and the microservice handling that call need to share the secret inorder for the JWTto work. The client wont be sending its secret int the JWT, instead the client and the microservices will be sharing the secret.

Comment: If your model is like this 
Client ---> Your Microservice ----> Other Microservice.
Do Other Microservices need authentication?

Comment: In this case yes. The first microservice has the client secret of the second microservice. The problem is that when I create an access token in the first microservice to call the second, the client secret is not in the token

Comment: client_secret shouldn't appear in the token... As you know, when you create a client secret in Azure AD portal, you need to copy and save the secret in some place upon you generate it, because you can't see the complete value in Azure AD since then. In the meantime, you can see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#claims-in-access-tokens), that really doesn't have a client secret scope.

Comment: Basically, you should use on-behalf-of flow here, and you may take a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74311506/how-to-create-client-assertion-and-assertion-in-on-behalf-of-flow/74313765#74313765

Comment: You are a little confused on what the secret is used for perhaps? Like in Encryption a key is used to encrypt the plaintext into a cypher, here the secret is basically used in the encryption as well. If you have access to second microservice in your case, you need to check that whether that service and your own service sharing the same secret for JWT, if not, then you wont be able to communicate with that service.

Comment: @TinyWang The on behalf of flow worked. Can you add it as an answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario(you have a client + several micro services), you authenticated in the client and use the access token to call your service, and now you want to make your service to call another service, you should use [on-behalf-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) here.

The whole flow can be understood as, in the server side, using request below to generate a new access token and use it to send request to another service.

```
POST /oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
client_id={azure_ad_app_id}
&client_secret={client_secret}
&assertion={access token to this request}
&scope={scope}
&requested_token_use=on_behalf_of
```

And if the micro service is an asp.net core app, then it should integrate `Microsoft.Identity.Web` in the application, and we can use `var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "api://xx/scope_name" });` to generate the on-behalf-of token.