# How do I access MS Graph from .NET API using Graph SDK and Azure AD B2C

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi, microsoft-graph-sdks, .net-7.0

Currently I have attempted to setup Graph in my .NET 7 API with the following code in `Program.cs`.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("GraphAPI"));
```

When I inject `GraphServiceClient` and make a request like so:

`var user = await _graphServiceClient.Users["5d4c0c45-a9ee-4772-9bba-0c0cf2d8691b"].Request().GetAsync();`

An exception is thrown:

`{"'<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."}`

Conversely, if I setup `GraphServiceClient` manually in the class and run the same request, it works fine.

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = _config["ClientId];
var clientSecret = "_config["ClientSecret]";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
```

I could just set this up in it's own class and use that but I think I'm missing something. I'm using this code in a protected API with a React UI with Azure AD **B2C** used for authentication.

What have I missed?

Comment: `.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration)` expects that you have a configuration section named `AzureAd` in your `appsettings.json`. Do you have it set?

Comment: It is yeah, included clientid and client secret. All other aspects of auth work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is Client(React) + Server(.net 7 web api), now you want to use graph api in your web api, you have 2 solutions. One is using client credential flow like what you mentioned which is worked for you, another one is using on-behalf-of flow which allows you to inject `graphclient` and no need to provide an [auth_provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider).

The normal flow for Client + Server mode should be, the API is protected by Azure AD, so the client should generate the access token which contained the correct scope/role along with the request to the web API. And in on-behalf-of flow, the auth provider comes from this incoming access token, which means on behalf of the valid of to generate another access token to call ms graph api.

Let's see a sample here. In my frontend app, I send request to my api from my client(my client is also written in c#)

```
var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "api://3743-xxxxx-ed41b2d7/Tiny.Read" });

var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,"https://localhost:7212/WeatherForecast")
{
    Headers =
    {
        { HeaderNames.Authorization, "Bearer "+ accessToken}
    }
};

var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

And my API, like what you did in `Program.cs`.

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Then in controller,

```
public WeatherForecastController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<string> GetAsync()
        {
            var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            var name = user.DisplayName;
            string a = "{\"displayName\":\""+ name +"\",\"age\":18}";
            return "world";
        }
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I updated the authentication setup as you mentioned. I'm getting the access token and sending it to the API but when I make the Graph request, I still get the error: `'<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.`. Is there anything as part of the access token I could check and verify?

Comment: ` getting the access token and sending it` could you pls decode the token and use it in [this request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75433547/14574199) to test if it can generate new access token?

Comment: I get `"AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key was not found.].`. Access token came from client after logging in. JWT didn't include Graph scopes from app registration, if that makes a difference?

https://imgur.com/a/gN1pMM6

Comment: scope here should use the graph api scope.. I see in your screenshot it's `API.Access`.  By the way, about your scenario I have [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74313765/14574199) here which may help as well.

Comment: Thanks, will this work with B2C? Requests seem to be much more different here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens

Comment: sorry I ignored before that you used b2c, but when using simple graph api to query users, it's the same in b2c, you can see this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations

Comment: I didn’t. Using B2C has proven to be problematic, I’m currently looking at other identity solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To Use MSAL.NET to sign in users with social identitie:

[image]

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-aad-b2c-considerations#authority-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-and-policy

Hope this helps.