# Why am i getting an invalid access token from On-behalf-of-flow

Tags: ms-word, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, on-behalf-of

When I am using On-Behalf -Of-Flow and hitting /token endpoint with "common" tenant and word as middletier token as assertion with scopes as "openid profile offline_access user.read" i get a malinformed token , but it works for /me endpoint of microsoft graph, but not works for other microsoft api's such as GetAllFolders api etc.

```
{
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  scope: 'User.Read openid profile',
  expires_in: 2148,
  ext_expires_in: 2148,
  access_token: 'EwBoA8l6BAAUAOyDv0l6PcCVu89kmzvqZmkWABkAAcC8ou4ZlNy/KWYLLdVH0vH5mX0MiAuWOx+gxF.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................9bsbChhpSgTqaDAn2/5e2ol0e+jVUfSFYGNfr45kqBZUoB32Q2HFI1p8wpIdQPOMXfQI=',
  refresh_token: 'M.C105_BAY.-CW5CZWj8ujA1gjI*WNj2u.........................................................................................................................................Ld5Mv40fbrVowHZdbrDkTPFTaKFidgiAN!qZhx472zJNxxnW0iVOFfQqNtU$',
  id_token: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJS.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................83ZPxcotsRG-wGV30ULbnXyI8PFg'
}
```

Normally a accessToken starts with "ey..." , when we add more scopes we get different responses such as :-

```
    {   error: 'invalid_grant',  
  error_description: "AADSTS500202: User account '{EmailHidden}' from external identity provider 'live.com' is not supported for API version '2.0'. Microsoft account pass-thru users and guests are not supported by the tenant-independent endpoint.\r\n"
    
     }
```

Comment: What code do you use?

Comment: Could you include the scope you are adding and the API/Graph query you are trying to call?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I use this code (C#) :-
                if (type == "onBehalf")
                {  postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"));
                    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("requested_token_use", "on_behalf_of"));
                    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("requested_token_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:saml1"));
                    postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("assertion", accessToken));
                }

Comment: @Rukmini scopes i include are "openid profile"

Comment: Could you also include the Graph query you are executing to GetAllFolders?

Comment: @Rukmini var folderOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
                {
                    new QueryOption("expand", "listItem"),
                };var folderData = await _graphServiceClient.Sites[_siteId].Drive.Root.Children.Request(folderOptions).Select(file => new
                    {
                        file.Id,file.Name,
                        file.Folder,
                        file.Package,
                        file.LastModifiedDateTime,
                        file.SharepointIds,
                        file.CreatedDateTime
                    }) .GetAsync();

Comment: @Rukmini https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root/children

Comment: Did you get the access token successfully using the OBO Flow?

Comment: @Rukmini yes i do get the access token 
it looks like this with /common endpoint : - 
  access_token: 'EwBoA8l6BAAUAOyDv0l6PcCVu89kmzvqZmkWABkAAcC8ou4ZlNy/KWYLLdVH0vH5mX0MiAuWOx+gxF.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................MXfQI='

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253732/discussion-between-rukmini-and-yatin-tripathi).

Comment: I think you can write a sample using OBO flow

Comment: @TinyWang can you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: oh sorry, forget to at Rukmini. He is very helpful, and I think if you can share your requirements, he may write a sample for you. because your issue looks weird.

Comment: Okay thank you @TinyWang, a sample using OBO flow will surely help my case.

Comment: and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74313765/14574199). by the way, is your test using an account like xx@xx.onmicrosoft.com? if not, could you pls use that kind of account?

Comment: @TinyWang my problem is with /common endpoint for personal accounts. Work and school accounts are working with OBO flow.
The token which i get using using "common" as tenant does  not work for other graph api's except /me endpoint.
The access  token is also different for  personal accounts , it's difficult to decode.

Comment: thank you for your sharing, but I don't have any other ideas then...

Comment: @Rukmini Zuhei recreated my issue in this link:-
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1287189/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-access-token-from-on-b?page=1&orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1255205#newest-answer-comment)

common-consent pattern for OBO will not work" I don't necessarily understand the whole "on-behalf-of-flow does not currently work for Microsoft Personal accounts"

currently list sites endpoint does not support delegated personal permission

Comment: Yeah, list sites doesnt support Microsoft Personal Accounts.

Comment: @Rukmini one last question will {common} tenant work for compare feature using openxml?

Comment: Sorry, I dont have idea on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: The scenario you are trying to achieve doesn't work for Personal Microsoft accounts. To resolve the issue you have to make use of work or school accounts.

I tried to generate the **access token using Personal Microsoft Account** and got the error like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/6897a344-7c37-441b-aa3c-dcff235035c7/drive/root/children
```

[image]

To resolve the issue, I generated the token using OBO flow like below signing in with Work or School account:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:scope
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:-ClientSecret
```

[image]

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:Scope
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion:
requested_token_use:on_behalf_of
```

[image]

Now, by using the above access token, I am able to list the sites successfully like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/6897a344-7c37-441b-aa3c-dcff235035c7/drive/root/children
```

[image]

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: This is correct but Gaining consent for the middle-tier application doesn't makes sense then.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, currently list sites endpoint does not support delegated personal permission. So maybe that's the cause of the problem,

I also tested it locally, and the same account returns different results under different {tenant} value.

This link might help is anyone faces same issue :-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1287189/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-access-token-from-on-b?page=1&orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1255205#newest-answer-comment